# Do I make the sneak check on the patrol marker or confront monsters first?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-curse-of-dark-pharaoh

When I end my turn in the street where there are monsters and a patrol marker, do I encounter the monsters first or perform the sneak check to avoid being arrested. Do I get to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf) covers this.  You make your evade check first, and then monsters.

> **Q:** At the end of your Movement Phase, do you fight monsters
>   before making the Evade check against Martial Law
>   to see if you are arrested or after?
>
> **A:** After the Evade check against Martial Law.

Comment: I don't know anything about "Martial Law" (appears to be an Innsmouth Horror feature) or how the feature differs in magnitude / scope / rules to the patrol markers in Curse of the Dark Pharaoh. This seems the best answer given no other sources unless the Martial Law feature has a much different feel.